# Checking If Database In Restoring State

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a T-SQL script that drops a database and then restores it.  The script runs against a SQL Server 2008 database.  Sometimes there is a problem with the backup file and the database gets stuck in the restoring state.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'dbname')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [dbname]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH 
    ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'dbname')
BEGIN
    DROP DATABASE [dbname]
END

RESTORE DATABASE [dbname]
FROM  DISK = N'C:\dbname.bak'
WITH  FILE = 1,
NOUNLOAD,
STATS = 10
```

The next time the script runs the script generates the error message

```
ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state.
```

What is the best way to check if the database is in the restoring state before trying to run the ALTER DATABASE command?

EDIT: The RESTORE DATABASE command that I'm running doesn't use the NO RECOVERY option.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It sounds as though you are performing a database restore with the `NORECOVERY` option. The reason you would want to do this is if you were planning to apply subsequent transaction log backups after the initial restore.

If you only wish to restore a single database backup then remove the `NORECOVERY` clause. If you are restoring transaction log backups, the final restore must be done without the `NORECOVERY` clause or if the last was applied with `NORECOVERY` you can `RESTORE DATABASE DbName WITH RECOVERY` to finalize.

To answer your question:

**Method 1**

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('DatabaseName', 'Status')
```

See SQL Server Books Online: [DATABASEPROPERTYEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx)

**Method 2**

Review the sys.databases system view in order to determine the current state of a database. For example:

```
SELECT
    state,
    state_desc
    FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseName'
```

A state of 1 = RESTORING

See [Sys.Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) for documentation regarding this system view.

Comment: state_description is now state_desc in SQL 2008 r2

Comment: @Iain: It's also state_desc in SQL-Server 2005

Answer (score 3):

SELECT [DATABASEPROPERTYEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx) ('MyDb', 'Status')

Answer (score 1):

Others had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4254581/623735) doing a `RESTORE` with `pyodbc`. My [variation of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007965/623735) (with similar symptoms to yours) turned out to be an incorrect bak file.  This can be discovered with the following T-SQL, looking for incorrect `.mdf` or `.ldf` file names or database names:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\dbname.bak'
```

Answer (score 1):

Method 2:

```
SELECT
    state,
    state_desc
     FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = 'Databasename'
```

It is give me exact result.