# Waiting for DB restore to finish using sqlalchemy on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy, restore, pyodbc

I'm trying to automate my db restores during development, using TSQL on SQL Server 2008, using sqlalchemy with pyodbc as a transport.

The command I'm executing is:

"""CREATE DATABASE dbname

restore database dbname FROM DISK='C:\Backups\dbname.bak' WITH REPLACE,MOVE 'dbname_data' TO 'C:\Databases\dbname_data.mdf',MOVE 'dbname_log' TO 'C:\Databases\dbname_log.ldf'"""

Unfortunately, the in SQL Management Studio, after the code has run, I see that the DB remains in state "Restoring...".

If I restore through management studio, it works. If I use subprocess to call "sqlcmd", it works. pymssql has problems with authentication and doesnt even get that far.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: I had the exact same problem with sqlserver 2012, even using django to provide the connection `cursor`. Didn't work: `DROP` before `RESTORE`, `WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, NOUNLOAD`, `SET SINGLE_USER` before `RESTORE` and `SET MULTI_USER` after, `USE [master]` before `RESTORE`, `SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`. Like for you, each of these work when run in Management Studio.

Answer (score 4):

The BACKUP and RESTORE statements run asynchronously so they don't terminate before moving on to the rest of the code.

Using a while statement as described at http://ryepup.unwashedmeme.com/blog/2010/08/26/making-sql-server-backups-using-python-and-pyodbc/ solved this for me:

```
# setup your DB connection, cursor, etc
cur.execute('BACKUP DATABASE ? TO DISK=?', 
            ['test', r'd:\temp\test.bak'])
while cur.nextset():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Unable to reproduce the problem restoring directly from pyodbc (without sqlalchemy) doing the following:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string) # ensure autocommit is set to `True` in connection string
cursor = connection.cursor()
affected = cursor.execute("""CREATE DATABASE test
RESTORE DATABASE test FROM DISK = 'D:\\test.bak' WITH REPLACE, MOVE 'test_data' TO 'D:\\test_data.mdf', MOVE 'test_log' to 'D:\\test_log.ldf' """)
while cursor.nextset():
    pass
```

Some questions that need clarification:

- What is the code in use to do the restore using sqlalchemy?
- What version of the SQL Server ODBC driver is in use?
- Are there any messages in the SQL Server log related to the restore?

**Thanks to [geographika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179520/geographika) for the [Cursor.nextset()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#nextset) example!**

Comment: if restoring transaction logs were the holdup, then wouldn't running the TSQL in Management Studio fail similarly?

Comment: Yep, guess I didn't read carefully enough. Strange the exact T-SQL works with pyodbc, but not when sqlalchemy is used as a wrapper. Given the age of the question, we probably won't get answers to the questions to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Right. I'm working the identical prob now and am trying to duplicate your success and determine my answers to your questions.

Comment: @hobs With pyodbc 3.0.7 and SQL Server Native Client 11.0, I'm now getting the error: `[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.` If you really need to create the database beforehand, you're better off breaking up the create and restore. Otherwise, just run `RESTORE DATABASE` by itself - the database will be created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @hobs As a followup, I had to add to initialize a cursor and call [Cursor.nextset()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#nextset) as mentioned in [geographika's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/179520/geographika) answer in order for the restore to complete. Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed my problem which was that my bak file contained .mdf and .ldf files for a different database (misnamed my bak file). I also used `connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)` as you pointed out in your commented code. Don't know if that was part of the solution. Thanks for your detailed help. I'm using TDS version 7.2, SQL Server Express 2012, pyodbc 3.0.6. I did a connection.close() after all `CREATE` and `DROP` commands. Did not need a `connection.commit()` after `RESTORE`

Comment: @hobs Good catch on the .mdf and .ldf files - setting `autocommit=True` definitely was part of the solution, as backup and restore operations cannot run inside of a transaction (which is what you get with the default `autocommit=False`). Thanks for bringing my attention to an old, wrong answer for me to correct :)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Alchemy users, and thanks to geographika for the answer: I ended up using the “raw” DBAPI [connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) from the connection pool.

It is exactly as geographika's solution but with a few additional pieces:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
driver = 'SQL+Server'
name = 'servername'
sql_engine_str = 'mssql+pyodbc://'\
                     + name\
                     + '/'\
                     + 'master'\
                     + '?driver='\
                     + driver
engine = sa.create_engine(sql_engine_str, connect_args={'autocommit': True})

connection = engine.raw_connection()
try:
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  sql_cmd = """
        RESTORE DATABASE [test]
        FROM DISK = N'...\\test.bak'
        WITH FILE = 1,
         MOVE N'test'
         TO N'...\\test_Primary.mdf',
         MOVE N'test_log'
         TO N'...\\test_log.ldf',
         RECOVERY,
         NOUNLOAD,
         STATS = 5,
         REPLACE
        """
  cursor.execute(sql_cmd)
  while cursor.nextset():
       pass
except Exception as e:
  logger.error(str(e), exc_info=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Five things fixed my problem with identical symptoms.

1. Found that my test.bak file contained the wrong mdf and ldf files:

   ```
   >>> cursor.execute(r"RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'test.bak'").fetchall()    
   [(u'WRONGNAME', u'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL ...),
   (u'WRONGNAME_log', u'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL ...)]
   ```
2. Created a new bak file and made sure to set the `copy-only backup` option
3. Set the autocommit option for my connection.

   ```
   connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
   ```
4. Used the connection.cursor only for a single RESTORE command and nothing else
5. Corrected the `test_data` MOVE to `test` in my RESTORE command (courtesy of @beargle).

   ```
   affected = cursor.execute("""RESTORE DATABASE test FROM DISK = 'test.bak' WITH REPLACE, MOVE 'test' TO 'C:\\test.mdf', MOVE 'test_log' to 'C:\\test_log.ldf' """)
   ```