# Restoring SQL server backup via python starts but does not complete

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter, pyodbc, restore

I am trying to restore SQL server backup using python. I have a UI  built in Tkinter which accepts the filepath and other details like servername, databasename, etc. For testing I am just using localhost. There are two file that I have developed. One called tool.py that has the UI and the other file called Restorebackup.py which has the logic to restore the database. When you run the tool.py file and press the start button it asks you for the file path of the .dat_bak or .bak file that you want to restore. After choosing the .dat_bak file you wait for some time and you get the message as "Backup is restored". I go to SQL Server Management Studio and see the databases in localhost. It shows that backup is restoring with the blue arrow. Unfortunately it never completes and is stuck there forever. When I just run the Restorebackup.py by hardcoding filepath and other values it restores backup perfectly fine. Not sure what is the issue

Restorebackup.py file

```py
import pyodbc 
import os
#######################################################################################################################      
def restore_backup(selectedChoiceServer, selectedChoiceDatabase, selectedChoiceSchema, filePath):
    try:   
        driver= '{SQL Server}'        
        selectedChoiceServer="localhost"        
        db_environment= 'master'        
        username= 'sqlserverloginforlocalhost'        
        password='yourpassword'
        connectionString = (('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+selectedChoiceServer+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+ db_environment +';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)) 
        db_connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString, autocommit=True)
        cursor = db_connection.cursor()      
        cursor.execute("""RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '"""+filePath+"""'""")
        dataset = cursor.fetchall()
        YourMDFLogicalName = dataset[0][0]
        YourLDFLogicalName = dataset[1][0]
        if not os.path.exists('c:/mybackup/backuptest'):
            os.mkdir('c:/mybackup/backuptest')
        db_connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString, autocommit=True)
        sql = """  
        USE [master]
        RESTORE DATABASE [testdatabase] FROM  
        DISK = N'"""+filePath+"""' 
        WITH  FILE = 1
        ,RECOVERY
        ,  MOVE N'Service' TO N'C:/mybackup/backuptest/""" + YourMDFLogicalName + """.mdf'
        ,  MOVE N'Service_log' TO N'C:/mybackup/backuptest/""" + YourLDFLogicalName + """.ldf'
        ,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
        """ 
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db_connection.autocommit = False
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        print('Some Error Occured, so backup was not restored')
        print('Error is :' + str(e))
        return str(e)
#######################################################################################################################
```

tool.py file

```py
from tkinter import messagebox 
from tkinter import filedialog
import unknown_support
from Restorebackup import restore_backup
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk() 
    top = Tool (root)
    unknown_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

def destroy_Tool():
    root.destroy()

class Tool:
    def StartButtonAction(self):
        self.Button1.config(state=DISABLED)
        selectedChoiceServer = self.Text3.get('1.0','end-1c')
        selectedChoiceDatabase = self.Text1.get('1.0','end-1c')
        selectedChoiceSchema =   self.Text2.get('1.0','end-1c')  
        root.fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = ( ("bak files", "*.dat_bak"),("All files","*.*") ) )
        #root.fileName = root.fileName.replace('/', '\\')
        res = restore_backup(selectedChoiceServer, selectedChoiceDatabase, selectedChoiceSchema, root.fileName)
        if res == 1:
            messagebox.showinfo("Backup is restored", "Backup is restored")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error: ",res)

    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        top.geometry("600x450+761+233")
        top.title("Backup Restore Tool")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")    
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.choice = IntVar()
        self.databaseChoice = StringVar()

        self.Label1 = Label(top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.32, rely=0.38, height=26, width=58)
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Schema''')

        self.Label2 = Label(top)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.24, height=26, width=69)
        self.Label2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''Database''')

        self.Label3 = Label(top)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.10, height=26, width=69)
        self.Label3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''Server''')

        self.Text1 = Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.24, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.39)
        self.Text1.configure(background="#ffffffffffff")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=234)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap=WORD)


        self.Text2 = Text(top)
        self.Text2.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.38, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.39)
        self.Text2.configure(background="white")
        self.Text2.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text2.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text2.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text2.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text2.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text2.configure(width=234)
        self.Text2.configure(wrap=WORD)

        self.Text3 = Text(top)
        self.Text3.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.10, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.39)
        self.Text3.configure(background="white")
        self.Text3.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text3.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text3.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text3.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text3.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text3.configure(width=234)
        self.Text3.configure(wrap=WORD)


        self.Button1 = Button(top)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.58, height=33, width=186)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''Start''')
        self.Button1.configure(width=186)
        self.Button1.configure(command = self.StartButtonAction)


        self.Button2 = Button(top)
        self.Button2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.68, height=33, width=186)
        self.Button2.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button2.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button2.configure(text='''Quit''')
        self.Button2.configure(width=186)
        self.Button2.configure(command = destroy_Tool)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: What is the SQL you're using for the Restore? Perhaps you aren't using `WITH RECOVERY`?

Comment: The SQL statement to restore is there in the code. I tried WITH RECOVERY but still fails

Comment: The solution could be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254581/waiting-for-db-restore-to-finish-using-sqlalchemy-on-sql-server-2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for DB restore to finish using sqlalchemy on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254581/waiting-for-db-restore-to-finish-using-sqlalchemy-on-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just introduced some delay and made a few other changes and it worked for me. Please refer to the code as follows

```
    restoreddatabase =  selectedChoiceSchema + '-' + strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", gmtime()) +'import'
    connectionString = (('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+localserver+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+ db_environment +';UID='+localusername+';PWD='+ password)) 
    db_connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString, autocommit = True)
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '"""+filePath+"""'""")
    dataset = cursor.fetchall()
    filenames = []
    for i in dataset:
        filedetails = {}
        #print(i[0])
        #print(i[1][::-1][:(i[1][::-1]).find('\\')][::-1])
        filedetails['name'] = i[0]
        filedetails['withextension'] = i[1][::-1][:(i[1][::-1]).find('\\')][::-1]
        filenames.append(filedetails)
    if not os.path.exists(rootfolder + '/'+ restoreddatabase):
        os.mkdir(rootfolder + '/'+ restoreddatabase)

    print(filePath)
    filePath = filePath.replace("/","\\")
    rootfolder = rootfolder.replace("/","\\")
    sql = """  
    USE [master]
    RESTORE DATABASE ["""+restoreddatabase+"""] FROM  
    DISK = N'"""+filePath+"""' 
    WITH  FILE = 1
    ,RECOVERY
    """ 
    for i in filenames:
        sql = sql + """, MOVE N'""" +i['name'] +"""' TO N'"""+ rootfolder +"""\\"""+ restoreddatabase+"""\\""" + i['withextension'] + """'"""

    sql = sql + """, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
    """ 
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db_connection1 = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    cursor1 = db_connection1.cursor()
    database_restored_sql = """select top 1 * from msdb.dbo.restorehistory order by restore_date desc"""
    cursor1.execute(database_restored_sql)
    dataset = cursor1.fetchall()
    tquery = """        
    SELECT session_id as SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')       
    """
    print('Percentage Restored: ', end = '', flush = True)
    #sys.stdout.write('Percentage Restored: ')
    while restoreddatabase != dataset[0][2]:
        #print('in while')
        sleep(5)
        cursor1.execute(database_restored_sql)
        dataset = cursor1.fetchall()
        cursor1.execute(tquery)
        tdataset = cursor1.fetchall()
        if len(tdataset) > 0:
            if tdataset[0][4] > 99.99:
                print(str(tdataset[0][4])[0:3] + '%',end = ' ', flush = True)
                #sys.stdout.write(str(tdataset[0][4])[0:3] + '% ')
            else:
                print(str(tdataset[0][4])[0:2] + '% ',end = ' ', flush = True)
                #sys.stdout.write(str(tdataset[0][4])[0:2] + '% ')
    db_connection.autocommit = False
```